# C#/UWP OutOfMemory when change ListView to horizontal

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, horizontal-scrolling

I have a ListView with about 700 entries (one Image per entry). The ListView works just fine in vertical scroll mode. But when I change it to Horizontal it crashes on the phone with an OutOfMemory Exception. 
I change the scroll direction with code from Microsoft:

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

It seems like Lord Windows is trying to load the complete list at once when the Orienation is changed. Anyone else experience this issue, maybe even provide a solution?

Comment: Does content of your ListView has bindings? Do you have UWP app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `StackPanel` you loose virtualization. So all the 700 entries are in memory at once when you scroll the list. Use `VirtualizingStackPanel` or better, use `GridView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: May I ask why it would be better GridView over ListView?

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Shame that MS does not mention this on their help page.

Comment: @fillobotto GridView is basically a ListView intended for horizontal scrolling. At least in 8.1.